# Display view results based on two values NOT matching

Tags: views, workflows, workbench

I am trying to filter view results based on two fields 'Workbench moderation: Latest revision ID (Latest Draft ID)' and 'Content revision: Revision ID (Published)'.

What I want to happen is if the Latest Draft ID doesn't match the Content Revision ID (Published) then it will show the fields. However if they match, it show the fields.

[image: Picture of view settings]

[image: View Results]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I used the 'Revision translation affected' (Indicates if the last edit of a translation belongs to current revision.)

That either dumps out yes or no, set the filter to only show those with yes as an answer.